# Sorting a List with Relative Positional Data

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

This is more of a conceptual programming question, so bear with me:

Say you have a list of scenes in a movie, and each scene may or may not make reference to past/future scenes in the same movie.  I'm trying to find the most efficient algorithm of sorting these scenes.  There may not be enough information for the scenes to be completely sorted, of course.

Here's some sample code in Python (pretty much pseudocode) to clarify:

```
class Reference:
    def __init__(self, scene_id, relation):
        self.scene_id = scene_id
        self.relation = relation


class Scene:
    def __init__(self, scene_id, references):
        self.id = scene_id
        self.references = references

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.id


def relative_sort(scenes):
    return scenes # Algorithm in question


def main():
    s1 = Scene('s1', [
        Reference('s3', 'after')
    ])
    s2 = Scene('s2', [
        Reference('s1', 'before'),
        Reference('s4', 'after')
    ])
    s3 = Scene('s3', [
        Reference('s4', 'after')
    ])
    s4 = Scene('s4', [
        Reference('s2', 'before')
    ])

    print relative_sort([s1, s2, s3, s4])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The goal is to have `relative_sort` return `[s4, s3, s2, s1]` in this case.

If it's helpful, I can share my initial attempt at the algorithm; I'm a little embarrassed at how brute-force it is.  Also, if you're wondering, I'm trying to decode the plot of the film "Mulholland Drive".

FYI: The Python tag is only here because my pseudocode was written in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you are looking for is a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting):

> In the field of computer science, a topological sort or topological ordering of a directed graph is a linear ordering of its vertices such that for every directed edge uv from vertex u to vertex v, u comes before v in the ordering. For instance, the vertices of the graph may represent tasks to be performed, and the edges may represent constraints that one task must be performed before another; in this application, a topological ordering is just a valid sequence for the tasks.

You can compute this pretty easily using a graph library, for instance, `networkx`, which implements [`topological_sort`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html). First we import the library and list all of the relationships between scenes -- that is, all of the directed edges in the graph

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> relations = [
    (3, 1),  # 1 after 3
    (2, 1),  # 2 before 1
    (4, 2),  # 2 after 4
    (4, 3),  # 3 after 4
    (4, 2)   # 4 before 2
]
```

We then create a directed graph:

```
>>> g = nx.DiGraph(relations)
```

Then we run a topological sort:

```
>>> nx.topological_sort(g)
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have included your modified code in my answer, which solves the current (small) problem, but without a larger sample problem, I'm not sure how well it would scale. If you provide the actual problem you're trying to solve, I'd love to test and refine this code until it works on that problem, but without test data I won't optimize this solution any further.

For starters, we track references as sets, not lists.

- Duplicates don't really help us (if "s1" before "s2", and "s1" before "s2", we've gained no information)
- This also lets us add inverse references with abandon (if "s1" comes before "s2", then "s2" comes after "s1").

We compute a min and max position:

- Min position based on how many scenes we come after
- This could be extended easily: If we come after two scenes with a min_pos of 2, our min_pos is 4 (If one is 2, other must be 3)
- Max position based on how many things we come before
- This could be extended similarly: If we come before two scenes with a max_pos of 4, our max_pos is 2 (If one is 4, other must be 3)
- If you decide to do this, just replace `pass` in `tighten_bounds(self)` with code to try to tighten the bounds for a single scene (and set anything_updated to true if it works).

The magic is in `get_possible_orders`

- Generates all valid orderings if you iterate over it
- If you only want one valid ordering, it doesn't take the time to create them all

Code:

```
class Reference:
    def __init__(self, scene_id, relation):
        self.scene_id = scene_id
        self.relation = relation

    def __repr__(self):
        return '"%s %s"' % (self.relation, self.scene_id)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.scene_id)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.scene_id == other.scene_id and self.relation == other.relation


class Scene:
    def __init__(self, title, references):
        self.title = title
        self.references = references
        self.min_pos = 0
        self.max_pos = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s (%s,%s)' % (self.title, self.min_pos, self.max_pos)

inverse_relation = {'before': 'after', 'after': 'before'}


def inverted_reference(scene, reference):
    return Reference(scene.title, inverse_relation[reference.relation])


def is_valid_addition(scenes_so_far, new_scene, scenes_to_go):
    previous_ids = {s.title for s in scenes_so_far}
    future_ids = {s.title for s in scenes_to_go}
    for ref in new_scene.references:
        if ref.relation == 'before' and ref.scene_id in previous_ids:
            return False
        elif ref.relation == 'after' and ref.scene_id in future_ids:
            return False
    return True


class Movie:
    def __init__(self, scene_list):
        self.num_scenes = len(scene_list)
        self.scene_dict = {scene.title: scene for scene in scene_list}
        self.set_max_positions()
        self.add_inverse_relations()
        self.bound_min_max_pos()
        self.can_tighten = True
        while self.can_tighten:
            self.tighten_bounds()

    def set_max_positions(self):
        for scene in self.scene_dict.values():
            scene.max_pos = self.num_scenes - 1

    def add_inverse_relations(self):
        for scene in self.scene_dict.values():
            for ref in scene.references:
                self.scene_dict[ref.scene_id].references.add(inverted_reference(scene, ref))

    def bound_min_max_pos(self):
        for scene in self.scene_dict.values():
            for ref in scene.references:
                if ref.relation == 'before':
                    scene.max_pos -= 1
                elif ref.relation == 'after':
                    scene.min_pos += 1

    def tighten_bounds(self):
        anything_updated = False
        for scene in self.scene_dict.values():
            pass
            # If bounds for any scene are tightened, set anything_updated back to true
        self.can_tighten = anything_updated

    def get_possible_orders(self, scenes_so_far):
        if len(scenes_so_far) == self.num_scenes:
            yield scenes_so_far
            raise StopIteration
        n = len(scenes_so_far)
        scenes_left = set(self.scene_dict.values()) - set(scenes_so_far)
        valid_next_scenes = set(s
                                for s in scenes_left
                                if s.min_pos <= n <= s.max_pos)
        # valid_next_scenes = sorted(valid_next_scenes, key=lambda s: s.min_pos * self.num_scenes + s.max_pos)
        for s in valid_next_scenes:
            if is_valid_addition(scenes_so_far, s, scenes_left - {s}):
                for valid_complete_sequence in self.get_possible_orders(scenes_so_far + (s,)):
                    yield valid_complete_sequence

    def get_possible_order(self):
        return self.get_possible_orders(tuple()).__next__()


def relative_sort(lst):
    try:
        return [s.title for s in Movie(lst).get_possible_order()]
    except StopIteration:
        return None


def main():
    s1 = Scene('s1', {Reference('s3', 'after')})
    s2 = Scene('s2', {
        Reference('s1', 'before'),
        Reference('s4', 'after')
    })
    s3 = Scene('s3', {
        Reference('s4', 'after')
    })
    s4 = Scene('s4', {
        Reference('s2', 'before')
    })

    print(relative_sort([s1, s2, s3, s4]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need a topological sort. A depth first traversal of the directed graph where the order relation forms the edges is all you need. Visit in post order. This the reverse of a topo sort. So to get the topo sort, just reverse the result.

I've encoded your data as a list of pairs showing what's known to go before what. This is just to keep my code short. You can just as easily traverse your list of classes to create the graph.

Note that for topo sort to be meaningful, the set being sorted must satisfy the definition of a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). Yours is fine. Order constraints on temporal events naturally satisfy the definition.

Note it's perfectly possible to create a graph with cycles. There's no topo sort of such a graph. This implementation doesn't detect cycles, but it would be easy to modify it to do so.

Of course you can use a library to get the topo sort, but where's the fun in that?

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Before -> After pairs dictating order. Repeats are okay. Cycles aren't.
# This is OP's data in a friendlier form.
OrderRelation = [('s3','s1'), ('s2','s1'), ('s4','s2'), ('s4','s3'), ('s4','s2')]

class OrderGraph:
  # nodes is an optional list of items for use when some aren't related at all
  def __init__(self, relation, nodes=[]):
    self.succ = defaultdict(set) # Successor map
    heads = set()
    for tail, head in relation:
      self.succ[tail].add(head)
      heads.add(head)
    # Sources are nodes that have no in-edges (tails - heads)
    self.sources = set(self.succ.keys()) - heads | set(nodes)

  # Recursive helper to traverse the graph and visit in post order
  def __traverse(self, start):
    if start in self.visited: return
    self.visited.add(start)
    for succ in self.succ[start]: self.__traverse(succ)
    self.sorted.append(start) # Append in post-order

  # Return a reverse post-order visit, which is a topo sort. Not thread safe.
  def topoSort(self):
    self.visited = set()
    self.sorted = []
    for source in self.sources: self.__traverse(source)
    self.sorted.reverse()
    return self.sorted
```

Then...

```
>>> print OrderGraph(OrderRelation).topoSort()
['s4', 's2', 's3', 's1']

>>> print OrderGraph(OrderRelation, ['s1', 'unordered']).topoSort()
['s4', 's2', 's3', 'unordered', 's1']
```

The second call shows that you can optionally pass values to be sorted in a separate list. You may but don't have mention values already in the relation pairs. Of course those not mentioned in order pairs are free to appear anywhere in the output.